# Cannot load bundle from framework

Tags: ios, nsbundle

Currently, I have constructed a framework which creating a view using an existing bundle.
And created a demo project using that framework.

I have already added the required bundle into the "Build Phase"->"Copy Bundle Resources" in both framework and my demo project.

However , when i init the view using "initWithNibName"
It display the error message :

> NSBundle /var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/BD51D9EC-91D0-46B8-B1C6-6225A669D4A5/Demo.app/bundleName.bundle> (not yet loaded)

It show that the demo project can get the bundle by the path, but cant loaded.
I have also used [Bundle load] method, but it seem not helpful to my issue.

Comment: Have you resoulved this issue?